# RSpec: Factory definition for associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following three models: `Product`, `Warehouse` and `Inventory`

```
# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :inventories
  has_many :warehouses, through: :inventories  
end

# app/models/warehouse.rb
class Warehouse < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :inventories
  has_many :products, through: :inventories
end

# app/models/inventory.rb
class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :warehouse
end
```

I have this factory for Inventory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :inventory do
    product { nil }
    warehouse { nil }
    item_count { 1 }
    low_item_threshold { 1 }
  end
end
```

How can I use this factory for Inventory or what changes are needed in my other factories so that I can have a spec something like this?

```
RSpec.describe Inventory, type: :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do
   expect(FactoryBot.build(:inventory)).to be_valid
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

What you need is to change the `:inventory` factory definition, like this

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :inventory do
    product
    warehouse
    item_count { 1 }
    low_item_threshold { 1 }
  end
end
```

This will "tell" factory bot to instantiate the associated objects (https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations)

But for this to work, you need to define `warehouse` and `product` factories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the `create` or `build` methods passing the name if the factory as a symbol:

```rb
  it "has a valid factory" do
   expect(create(:inventory)).to be_valid
 end

  # OR

  it "has a valid factory" do
   expect(build(:inventory)).to be_valid
 end
```

`create` will save the model while `build` will simply instantiate it. If you are having trouble getting your factories loaded, ensure they are in the [right place](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails/blob/master/README.md#automatic-factory-definition-loading).

Answer (score 0):

you might change definition of the class Inventory to:

```rb
# app/models/inventory.rb
class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
  belongs_to :warehouse, optional: true 
end
```

and you will get successful validation

```rb
inventory = FactoryBot.build(:inventory)
inventory.valid? #true
```

###############################################

Explanation:

to build valid Inventory object with current definition(like in question description) of the model its necessary to initialize associated objects also. So every time validation checks if `warehouse` and `product` attributes present.
But its possible to avoid such behaviour with associations attribute `optional: true`.

```rb
# app/models/inventory.rb
class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :warehouse
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :inventory do
    product { nil }
    warehouse { nil }
    item_count { 1 }
    low_item_threshold { 1 }
  end
end

inventory = FactoryBot.build(:inventory)
inventory.valid? #false 
inventory.errors.full_messages # ["Product must exist", "Warehouse must exist"]
```

> :required
> When set to true, the association will also have its
> presence validated. This will validate the association itself, not the
> id. You can use :inverse_of to avoid an extra query during validation.
> NOTE: required is set to true by default and is deprecated. If you
> don’t want to have association presence validated, use optional: true.
> https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to